# Can't inject code from background page while it works for popup page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following permissions in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
  "*//*/*",
  "http://*/",
  "https://*/",
  "activeTab",
  "tabs",
  "storage",
  "bookmarks"
]
```

Still I can't `executeScript` from background page, but somehow it works from popup page. I got the following error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://github.com/NeilLi1992/LightMarker/blob/master/js/background.js". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
>       at chrome-extension://aciimkfhggbanpmpngahlofjocidjfko/src/js/background.js:152:29

I tried to hard-coded `https://github.com/` in the permissions section, it still doesn't work.

---

I tested this piece of code in DevTools of the background page:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(728, { code: "alert(123);" });
```

728 is just the tabId I logged when a tab is created, so it's valid.

I got the above error from background devtools. But it works fine when I do it from popup's devtools.

Comment: It seems `"*//*/*"` might be invalid. But even without it, still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

Modify `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
  "*://*/_generated_background_page.html"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already figured out `*//*/*` is a invalid cross-origin permission. Use something like this instead.

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
```

or to provide a narrower scope of permissions.

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "activeTab"
  ]
```

For further reading about programmatic injection: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

Answer (score 0):

Please Don't load remote file, please download the relevant file in your project then try to execute it.

after doing this one still not working please add the file reference in web_accessible_resources attribute in manifest.json for more reference https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for other answers. However they don't seem to work.

I tried to fiddle the permission quite a lot, and I read through the programmatic injection page multiple times, but still couldn't get the background page to execute code.

At last I gave up and turned to content scripts, which painlessly worked. Now I open a port from the content script, and communicate with background page to prepare necessary information for the content script.

Just in case anyone else who's struggling, [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) seems to be your rescue.